# Given, particular, specific, any

Tags: vocabulary

I'm not sure which of the words from the title would be the best choice to indicate that I'm referring to a random consequence in general, in the context of the following sentence:

> Most often, a given/specific/particular consequence is the result of a
>   combination of many factors.

I want to say that hardly ever anything happens as a result of only factor, i.e that many factors contribute to the occurrence of any effect.

Comment: _Arbitrary_ means 'arbitrarily chosen', which says nothing about its distribution. Roughly equivalent to free-choice _any_.

Comment: consequences resulting from multiple factors

Comment: Thank you for the help John Lawler, but I'm not sure I understand. Thank you Lambie, but I'm not sure how to rephrase my sentence using your phrase.

Comment: What about excluding the adjective altogether? "Most often" already implies that the following clause holds over some random choice.

Comment: Most often, a consequence is the result of a combination of many factors. will work Benjamin? You're not happy with any of the adjectives used in this sentence?

Comment: Why not *random* itself?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion alwayslearning, but I'm not sure it would be the word I'm looking for in this context. Now I look at it, maybe "Any particular consequence is the result of a combination of many factors". Maybe "any particular" would work here?